# cleaning up centos install

Tags: centos, filesystems

I am relatively new to using linux but have a vps with centos installed with uTorrent installed via wine.

The VPS has 50GB of space which I have noticed all of that is being taken up by the home/admin/ directory.

Inside this directory are two other directories - Desktop and Downloads which downloads only takes up 34gb and Desktop which says nothing due to all that is on there is 1 icon to utorrent.

What could be taking up the extra 16GB of space?

EDIT:

the files were in /home/admin/.local/share/Trash/files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll bet it's temp files used by uTorrent. Try checking under `/home/admin/.wine/dosdevices/c:/`. The `/home/admin/.wine` directory is hidden since its name starts with a period, that's why you probably didn't check it.

You can also use `find` to check for files bigger than, say, 50 MB, a la:

```
find /home/admin -size +50M
```

Adjust the 50M accordingly (+100M for finding files bigger than 100MB, +1G for files bigger than 1 GB, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm a fan of something like this for figuring out where all my space is going:

```
du -mcx | sort -n
```

After cd'ing to the directory you're investigating, of course.

The biggest items will be the top level directories, but you should be able to see which bottom-level directories are the problem.

You can add a "-a" to the du command-line to see individual files listed.

The "-m" makes it output in megabytes; you can use "-k" for kilobytes instead.  The "-x" prevents it crossing filesystem boundaries, which is useful if you're looking for something on the / partition, for instance.  The -c produces a grand total.

The biggest directories will pop out right at the bottom of the list.

Or format it upside down and just give the top 20:

```
du -mx | sort -rn | head -n 20
```

Answer (score 0):

With OpenVZ there are soft and hard quotas.  I within the VPS the disk size will appear as the soft quota until you exceed it. Maybe your VPS is OpenVZ?

Answer (score 0):

`xdiskusage` is an excellent disk space usage visualizer - you can see the problem areas almost immediately.

Comment: I'm also a big fan of Filelight.

Comment: Nifty. One of the killer features for me and xdiskusage is the ability to pretty much copy the static binary anywhere I like or even just pipe the output of `du` into it. Very handy working on remote disparate systems.